# Receive GCM Topic Push message in Titanium

Tags: android, push-notification, titanium, google-cloud-messaging, channel

I don't have any more hair to tear out and need help..

I want to send messages to a topic (or channel) from a server (via GCM) so it reaches all devices subscribing to that topic.

Sending push messages to individual devices works fine and the format for sending to topics is the same, except for specifying a deviceToken, specify the topic in the for /topics/mytopic

This is described here:

https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/downstream
https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/topic-messaging

On the Titanium side (Android for now but the plan is IOS too later on) I register the device to a channel "myChannel". I can verify this by a success message returned and also in Appcelerators console.

Now, I simulate a server with curl, and send a message to "myChannel" to GCM. The message response with success and I receive back a message_id from GCM.

```
curl -H "Content-Type:application/json" -H "Authorization:key=APIKEY" --data '{"to": "/topics/myChannel","data": {"payload":{ "message": "Hi!" } }}' https://gcm-http.googleapis.com/gcm/send
```

My problem is that this message is not routed to the device.
I am guessing there is some syntax conversion needed between the channel subscribed to in Titanium and the one I use to GCM but I don't know.

The funny thing is, as soon I put in the deviceToken in curl it works perfectly.

Am I missing something fundamental here? Is the channel not there to route the same message to multiple devices subscribing to it?
Any help, clues are much appreciated.

My code looks like this:

```
// Require the module
var CloudPush = require('ti.cloudpush');  

// Initialize the module
CloudPush.retrieveDeviceToken({
    success: deviceTokenSuccess,
    error: deviceTokenError
});

CloudPush.addEventListener('callback', receivePush);

function receivePush(evt) {
    alert("Notification received: " + JSON.stringify(evt.payload));
}

function deviceTokenSuccess(e) {
    Alloy.Globals.DeviceToken = e.deviceToken;
    Titanium.API.info(Alloy.Globals.DeviceToken);

    // Subscribe to topic 
    var Cloud = require("ti.cloud");
    var subscribe_data = {
        device_token: Alloy.Globals.DeviceToken,
        channel: Alloy.Globals.topicChannelID,
        type: Ti.Platform.name == 'android' ? 'android' : 'ios'
    };

    Cloud.PushNotifications.subscribeToken(
        subscribe_data, function (e) {
            if (e.success) {
                Titanium.API.info('Subscribed successfully');
            } else {
                Titanium.API.error('Error subscribing');
            }
        });
}

// Something went wrong getting the device token
function deviceTokenError(e) {
    Titanium.API.error('Failed ' + e.error);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GCM doesn't know about channels. That's something Arrow tracks and translates to the subscribed tokens. So you need to send push via the Arrow API or Appcelerator Dashboard.

http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Sending_and_Scheduling_Push_Notifications

http://docs.appcelerator.com/arrowdb/latest/#!/api/PushNotifications

Comment: Thanks for this information, it basically means that Titanium doesn't support GCM topic messaging. The terminology and border between GCM and Titanium was not trivial for me.

Comment: It means that like more push providers we take care of the channels and tokens so that in case GCM changes you don't have to worry about that.